# start Class from main

Tags: c#

how can I call Class from Main?
Don't excpect return from it as it should put its cata to another Class to use for Main later (to build GIU depending on result)

```
namespace Control
{ 

public class Handler
{

    static CountdownEvent countdown;
    static int upCount = 0;
    static object lockObj = new object();
    const bool resolveNames = true;

    public static void GetEventout()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var K = LocalIP.GetLocalIPAddress();
        string[] ipParts = K.Split('.');

        string l = ipParts[1];
        int n = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(l, out n);
        Console.WriteLine(n);
        if (n < 200)
        {
            string ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + ".";
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                string ippart = ipBase + i + ".";
                for (int j = 1; j < 255; j++)
                {
                    var ip = ippart + j;
                    Ping p = new Ping();
                    p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
                    countdown.AddCount();
                    p.SendAsync(ip, 100, ip);
                    string k = resolveNames.ToString();

                    if (k.Contains(ipBase))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{k} working");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            countdown.Signal();
            countdown.Wait();
            sw.Stop();
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.WriteLine("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, upCount);
....
```

when done

```
Handler o= new Handler();
```

Main just exit with return 0 but dosnt do anything with "Handler"

Comment: Do you call any method on `o`? Because your code only calls the constructor, which is an implicit one in your example

Answer (score 0):

Duh!
I need to **"use google before ask dumb question"** little more...

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(Handler.GetEventout);
thread1.Start();
```